# Optaplanner : Incomplete justification list in solver

Tags: optaplanner

I am solving a roster assignment problem using optaplanner.
When the solver ends, I see logs like

```
INFO  [2019-03-25 22:42:41,486] org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver: Solving ended: time spent (4083), best score (-500hard/-6133758medium/-1477130soft)
```

After which I print the score justification list using

```
ScoreDirectorFactory<MyPlanningSolution> scoreDirectorFactory = solver.getScoreDirectorFactory();
ScoreDirector<MyPlanningSolution> guiScoreDirector = scoreDirectorFactory.buildScoreDirector();

guiScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(planningSolutionInstance);

for (ConstraintMatchTotal constraintMatchTotal : guiScoreDirector.getConstraintMatchTotals()) {
    String constraintName = constraintMatchTotal.getConstraintName();
    // The score impact of that constraint
    Score scoreTotal = constraintMatchTotal.getScoreTotal();
    this.logger.info("constraintName " + constraintName + " scoreTotal " + scoreTotal + " Justification List :");

    for (ConstraintMatch constraintMatch : constraintMatchTotal.getConstraintMatchSet()) {
        List<Object> justificationList = constraintMatch.getJustificationList();
        this.logger.info(justificationList.toString() + " Score : " + constraintMatch.getScore());
    }
}
```

This only print a few constraints:

```
constraintName Sample constraint1 scoreTotal -100hard/0medium/0soft Justification List :
[...] Score : -100hard/0medium/0soft
constraintName Sample constraint3 scoreTotal -400hard/0medium/0soft Justification List :
[...] Score : -100hard/0medium/0soft
[...] Score : -100hard/0medium/0soft
[...] Score : -100hard/0medium/0soft
[...] Score : -100hard/0medium/0soft
constraintName Sample constraint3 scoreTotal 0hard/-6133758medium/-1345422soft Justification List :
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-3125soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-625soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-25soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-16384soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-3125soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-3125soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-625soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-625soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-625soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-125soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-125soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-64soft
[...] Score : 0hard/0medium/-9soft
```

If you add up the score printed here, you get `-500hard/0medium/-28607soft`

As you can see there is are multiple constraint that are not printed here. The medium constraints are not logged at all. Plus lots of soft constraints are missing as well.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Call `guiScoreDirector.calculateScore()` after calling `guiScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(planningSolutionInstance)` .

Comment: Ok. I've added `guiScoreDirector.calculateScore()` after setting working solution. Waiting for the run to complete to see if this helps.

Can you also explain why is this step needed? And why would the absence of it cause a score mismatch?

Comment: Ran with this config. The constraint list adds up to the total score now.

Can you explain a bit more detail about why omitting the calculateScore() method led to incorrect justification list? What data does it show without this call?

Answer (score 0):

This could be score corruption. Turn on environmentMode FULL_ASSERT to prove it (let it run for a long time). If turning that on, stops the bug from occurring, try NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT instead.

Comment: But I do not write my own move selector. Is there any way the score could be corrupted even while using default move selector?

Comment: Also, in case there is a score corruption, what is expected to happen in the FULL_ASSERT and NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT  modes? Is the solver expected to throw an error and stop?

Comment: Yes, those assertion modes are to detect score corruption immediately after it happens.

Comment: Ok I ran this. Been running for almost 2 days now in FULL_ASSERT mode. Don't see any error logs. Only logs coming are through the BestSolutionChangedEvent listener. How do I proceed?

Comment: Ok so I stopped the solver running in FULL_ASSERT mode after 97 hours. I did not see this issue in the result.
I also ran this in NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT mode. It ran for 50 hours. I see incomplete justification list in this mode too. However, it did not throw any error. Why is that?

Comment: Then this is not score corruption.